# Is it possible to log which AD user called a Logic App workflow?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Our current Proof of Concept makes use of Azure Logic Apps workflows to perform calculations and returns this result. Our client would like to monitor when and by who theseworkflows are called/triggered. Is this possible to do in Azure Monitor/Log Analytics/Application Insights?

From my own research it seems that the above Azure resources are only able to register when triggers happend with further diagnostics, but not which AD user triggered the action.

Any advice or knowledge sharing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put simply, I don’t believe so. Logging by user activity is very scarce in Azure as it is. However, would love to see if someone has an answer that doesn’t tend towards “no”. We all want it at times.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Azure Activity log contains information about who triggered the manual Logic App run. You can check it in the 'Activity log' section in the Azure portal. Here is how the typical event looks like for manual trigger activated by user in the Azure portal:
[image]

If you go into details of the event you will see the full JSON object containing information about the user, IP address from which user was logged and more. These activity logs can be forwarded to Log Analytics workspace for extended storage and analytics.

Answer (score 0):

1:  To Know when the logic app triggered, integrate the log analytics to Azure Logic App and follow the below process:-

- we have enabled log analytics workspace while creating logic app.
  [image]
- Run logic app twice.
- Added diagnostic setting in logic app as shown below.
  [image]
- Once added, go to `Diagnostics` in logic app.
- You can view when the logic app was called using report below:[image]

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics)

2:  To know who the users is/are accessed the logic app, integrate the app insights to Azure Logic App:-

- Using application insights also we can view report for logic app.
- If you are calling logic app through angular or any UI, you can configure app insights in code. In this way we can get details of user who run the logic app.